# `-Xms` and `-Xmx` in java 1.6 & 1.8

Tags: java, memory

In my machine, I tried two difference versions of Java with the same command, but only one of them is working.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468-11M4833)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-468, mixed mode)

$ java -Xms1024000m -Xmx2048000m HelloWorld
'java -Xms1024000m -Xmx2048000...' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

But with jdk 1.8:

```
$ java version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)

$ java -Xms1024000m -Xmx2048000m HelloWorld
Hello, world!
```

Not sure why it's different?

---

PS: My machine (`OSX 10.11.1 (15B42)`) has 16G Ram, and here I give `java` a much big memory setting `1024000m`(`1T`) to see if it can work. I'm curious why with jdk 1.8, it doesn't give any errors.

My `top`:

```
Processes: 370 total, 5 running, 15 stuck, 350 sleeping, 1781 threads
17:14:59
Load Avg: 1.62, 1.56, 1.61  CPU usage: 4.1% user, 3.54% sys, 92.43% idle   SharedLibs: 125M resident, 15M data, 7908K linkedit.
MemRegions: 220057 total, 4808M resident, 111M private, 1500M shared. PhysMem: 12G used (3045M wired), 4273M unused.
VM: 1083G vsize, 527M framework vsize, 33266913(0) swapins, 36305763(0) swapouts. Networks: packets: 256063947/286G in, 534051232/503G out.
Disks: 13058865/366G read, 15889283/505G written.
```

Comment: What are your specs (especially memory)? For me the second version crashes as well (with 1.8.0_72-b15/25.72-b15 though).

Answer (score 1):

`-Xms1024000m` is about 1 ***Terabyte*** of memory or about 1000GB.  I think you mean to use `-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m`

Comment: I think the problem is why java 6 bug with that amount of memory, while java 8 seems to ignore it, despite after allocating 1TB of memory

Comment: You are correct, but still curious why JVM8 didn't failed to pre-allocate memory.

Comment: Maybe it falls back to defaults if it finds unusable settings?

Comment: @JimGarrison AFAIK there are systems with 1TB out there, so I don't see why the JVM would deem this unusable.

Comment: The JVM already examines the total memory available and sets defaults (1/64 and 1/8 of total for -Xms and -Xmx) so it's quite possible if the numbers given exceed the total available it just falls back to defaults.